# most effcient way to merge multiple large data tables in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, merge

I have look around to find an answer for this question to make sure I avoid duplicates. I hope I have not overlooked anything.

I have around ~60 tables with each 2 columns. An ID and a corresponding value.
The IDs are overlapping across tables and each table has around ~2mill rows.
I will need to do some statistics on each ID. For example mean(table1.value, table2.value, table3.value ....).

My question is essentially. What is the fastest way to do this.

I have tried 2 approaches so far:

1. Merging: I merge table1 and table2 to tableA, table3 and table4 to tableB, then tableA and tableB....and so on.

With this approach I pretty fast reach a memory limit.

2. Going through each id: I use an index of all IDs and go through each table ala `SELECT value FROM tableA WHERE id=row[id]`

This just takes ages and I would not finish the query within the next month. And from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42998/are-individual-queries-faster-than-joins) it seems I should prefer joins.

Thus another question:
Would a partial join with subsequent stacking of the resulting merged tables be more efficient?

Comment: What exactly does "overlapping" mean? Are there any missing IDs?

Comment: Thanks so much for replying! Yes, some tables have values for a certain ID some do not. So yes there are missing IDs in some tables.

Comment: Is there some table that is guaranteed to have all IDs?

Comment: Yes.  I have such a table. However it has around  ~13 million rows

Comment: Why the "however"? You need 13 million rows in the output, don't you?

Comment: There might be less....so there might be some IDs not present in all tables